# How to load a static content in index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I was using vue-cli with webpack for my project and was loading an image in index.html like this
// index.html

```
<html>
    ...
    <style>
        .tag1 { background-image: url('<%= require('@/assets/icons/a123.svg') %>'); }
    </style>
    ...
</html>
```

how to load the icon in vite based index.html file? I tried
`url(/assets/icons/a123.svg)` but its throwing 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the svg file to /public folder and then u can access it like `<img src="/a123.svg" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can create function, [check vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url)

```
const useImage = ((url) => {
  return new URL(`/src/${url}`, import.meta.url).href;
});
```

and create global property in `main.js`:

```
app.config.globalProperties.$image = useImage;
```

then use it like:

```
$image(imageUrl)
```